# SQL ORACLE make result in one row

Tags: sql, oracle, row

I'm using ORACLE 11G , I want to make a query but I dont know how it works , and if is it possible:
This is my query :

```
SELECT  DC.CLEF_NAME,DC.CLEF_X, DC.CLEF_Y, DC.CLEF_COL, DC.CLEF_ROW, DC.CLEF_CLASSCOLOR ,DCO.COLOR_NAME,DCO.COLOR_VALUE
FROM DASHBOARD_SAVE DS 
LEFT JOIN DASHBOARD_CLEF DC ON DC.DASHBOARD_UID = DS.DASHBOARD_UID 
LEFT JOIN DASHBOARD_COLOR DCO ON DCO.CLEF_UID = DC.CLEF_UID
WHERE DC.REGROUPEMENT_UID is null and DS.DASHBOARD_USERID = 'testok'
```

I got the result :

```
TESTDECLEF  1   1   1   1   BLUE    1   RED
TESTDECLEF  1   1   1   1   BLUE    2   PINK
```

But I want to get :

```
                                1   2
 --------------------------------------
TESTDECLEF  1   1   1   1 BLUE RED  PINK
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Is the number of rows that need to be transformed to column is fixed or variable ? I mean will you always have 2 values (so 1 new column) or sometimes more, sometimes less ? could you please provide a better example ?

Comment: @Gosfly Hello , I can have N values is dynamic. Is from a table "DASHBOARD_COLOR" , this table have a STRANGER KEY ,I make a JOIN

Answer (score 0):

I am considering that `color_name` is 1,2 and `color_value` is PINK, RED.

You can use `pivot` as following:

```
Select * from
(SELECT  DC.CLEF_NAME,DC.CLEF_X, DC.CLEF_Y, DC.CLEF_COL, DC.CLEF_ROW, DC.CLEF_CLASSCOLOR ,DCO.COLOR_NAME,DCO.COLOR_VALUE
FROM DASHBOARD_SAVE DS 
LEFT JOIN DASHBOARD_CLEF DC ON DC.DASHBOARD_UID = DS.DASHBOARD_UID 
LEFT JOIN DASHBOARD_COLOR DCO ON DCO.CLEF_UID = DC.CLEF_UID
WHERE DC.REGROUPEMENT_UID is null and DS.DASHBOARD_USERID = 'testok')
Pivot
(Max(COLOR_VALUE) for COLOR_NAME IN (1 as 1, 2 as 2)
);
```

Or you can use `conditional aggregation` as following:

```
SELECT  DC.CLEF_NAME,DC.CLEF_X, DC.CLEF_Y, DC.CLEF_COL, DC.CLEF_ROW, DC.CLEF_CLASSCOLOR,
Max(case when DCO.COLOR_NAME = 1 then  DCO.COLOR_VALUE end) as 1,
Max(case when DCO.COLOR_NAME = 2 then  DCO.COLOR_VALUE end) as 2
    FROM DASHBOARD_SAVE DS 
    LEFT JOIN DASHBOARD_CLEF DC ON DC.DASHBOARD_UID = DS.DASHBOARD_UID 
    LEFT JOIN DASHBOARD_COLOR DCO ON DCO.CLEF_UID = DC.CLEF_UID
    WHERE DC.REGROUPEMENT_UID is null and DS.DASHBOARD_USERID = 'testok'
Group by 
DC.CLEF_NAME,DC.CLEF_X, DC.CLEF_Y, DC.CLEF_COL, DC.CLEF_ROW, DC.CLEF_CLASSCOLOR;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for you'r reply , but my number of colors is dynamic, I can have 5 colors for example .

Comment: A dynamic number of columns are not supported in the oracle until you use the dynamic query.

Comment: So it no possible for me to get this ?

Comment: It is possible but you need to use pl/sql with dynamic query.